# How to use visual studio and database file in another pc

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

I have created a software in c# windowsforms and also created a database in MS SQL SERVER.  I want to know that how can i run my software in another computer without installation of visual studio.

I have set connectionstring to my servername in visual studio, but in another computer would i need to install visual studio just to change the connectionstring?

Comment: what about connection string how can other computer accessible my servername?

Comment: btw i have app.config file can i add connection string throw notepad?

Comment: It depends how to get the connection string, recommend to move your connection string to app.config then tell the program to read the app.config's connection string

Comment: so how can i change the connection string ? :(

Comment: Oh I misread your question, yes since your connection string is already in your **app.config**, you can simply edit it via **Notepad**; _Notepad++_ or any other text editor.  **app.config** is merely a _text file_.  Visual Studio **is not** required to be installed for that.

Comment: Thanks Micky, do you work like this before?